# How can I make a request with Axios to upload a 4GB video, and this video can be in .mp4, .mov, etc. format?

Tags: reactjs

I have been implementing this code, but to some extent, it works, it only uploads 9% of the video, and it seems to be getting canceled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhtMu.png)

Comment: please share your code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading large files directly with a single request is usually not a good idea, especially when files are several GBs large. The connection could drop, the upload could timeout, or you could run into memory issues.

A more efficient way to upload large files is to split them into chunks and then upload each chunk separately. If one chunk fails to upload, you can simply retry it instead of re-uploading the whole file.

To chunk and upload a large file, you can use the slice() method in JavaScript's File

**components**

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
<button id="uploadBtn">Upload</button>
<div id="progressBar">0%</div>
```

JavaScript

```
const CHUNK_SIZE = 1000000; // 1MB
let offset = 0;
let file;
let token; // Your authorization token goes here

const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
const uploadBtn = document.getElementById("uploadBtn");
const progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");

fileInput.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  file = event.target.files[0];
});

uploadBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!file) {
    alert("Please select a file.");
    return;
  }

  progressBar.innerText = "Uploading...";
  offset = 0;
  uploadChunk();
});

function uploadChunk() {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  const blob = file.slice(offset, CHUNK_SIZE + offset);

  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

  fileReader.onload = async function (event) {
    try {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", new Blob([event.target.result]), "video-chunk");

      await axios
        .request({
          timeout: 1800000, // 30 minutes
          method: "POST",
          data: data,
          baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api/classes/uploadMedia",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
          onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            const percentage = Math.round(
              ((progressEvent.loaded + offset) / file.size) * 100
            );
            progressBar.innerText = `${percentage}%`;
          },
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error during chunk upload:", error);
          progressBar.innerText = "Upload failed";
        });

      offset += CHUNK_SIZE;

      if (offset < file.size) {
        uploadChunk();
      } else {
        progressBar.innerText = "Upload completed";
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during chunk upload:", error);
      progressBar.innerText = "Upload failed";
    }
  };
}
```